# Removing decimal dot

Tags: ios, swift, format, decimal

I'm currently developing a iOS (SWIFT) app where I need to remove the dot in decimal values.

For example:

> 20.50 -> 2050
>
> 20.00 -> 2000

Then add 2 zero at the end of the string.

In android i can do this:

```
java.text.DecimalFormat("#.00").format(amount))
```

but there is no such thing like DecimalFormat in Swift or am I wrong?

Comment: There is (NS)NumberFormatter, and you'll find dozens of Q&As about it.

Comment: Multiply by 100 and convert to string.

Answer (score -1):

`let num = 123.45
let str = String(format: "%.00f", num * 100)
print(str)`

prints `12345`